# Knockout min/max validation not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using a custom binding handler that I found at https://www.moonlightbytes.com/blog/useful-knockout-js-binding-handlers

It works very well to format input as currency. However, it also stops my Knockout min/max validation from working. I need a min of 1 and max of 200. Does anyone why this is occuring?

**Custom Binding**

```
function formatCurrency(symbol, value, precision) {
    return (value < 0 ? "-" : "") + symbol + Math.abs(value).toFixed(precision).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
  }

  function rawNumber(val) {
    return Number(val.replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, ""));
  }

  ko.bindingHandlers.currency = {
    symbol: ko.observable("$"),
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      //only inputs need this, text values don't write back
      if ($(element).is("input") === true) {
        var underlyingObservable = valueAccessor(),
          interceptor = ko.computed({
            read: underlyingObservable,
            write: function (value) {
              if (value === "") {
                underlyingObservable(null);
              } else {
                underlyingObservable(rawNumber(value));
              }
            }
          });
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, function () {
          return interceptor;
        }, allBindingsAccessor);
      }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      var symbol = ko.unwrap(allBindingsAccessor().symbol !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().symbol : ko.bindingHandlers.currency.symbol),
        value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      if ($(element).is("input") === true) {
        //leave the boxes empty by default
        value = value !== null && value !== undefined && value !== "" ? formatCurrency(symbol, parseFloat(value), 2) : "";
        $(element).val(value);
      } else {
        //text based bindings its nice to see a 0 in place of nothing
        value = value || 0;
        $(element).text(formatCurrency(symbol, parseFloat(value), 2));
      }
    }
  };
```

**ViewModel observable**

```
self.PriceAdvanced = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true, min: 1, max: 200 });
```

**Html**

```
<input class="form-control max225" type="text" id="PriceAdvanced" name="PriceAdvanced" data-bind="currency: PriceAdvanced" size="23" placeholder="$0.00" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Using-validation-with-a-custom-binding), and it worked perfectly:

> First, Create the custom binding, such as...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};
```

> ... then register the custom binding with knockout validation:

```
ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable('yourBindingName');
```